# socket io server connected = true, but client connected = false

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

iam new to the websocket, and i'm currently wanting to create a chat app using socket.io
i follow the documentation on the socket.io website and successfully connect the server to the client
but as i want to emit from the server to the client or vise versa i found out that my client is not connected to the server as the property disconnected = true

and my guess is that because of this i can't use the emit event
can someone explain whats going on?

note: both using version 2.2.0 of socket.io

here is the screenshot of whats happening

[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89AsE.png)

and the code of the server

```
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log(socket.connected)
  socket.on('message', ({ name, message }) => {
    console.log(name)
    console.log(message)
    io.emit('message', { name, message })
  })
})

http.listen(4000, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 4000')
})
```

and here is the screenshot of the client

[client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs0T1.png)

and here is the code of the client

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import io from "socket.io-client"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ message: "", name: "" })
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([])

  const socketRef = useRef()

  useEffect(
    () => {
      socketRef.current = io("http://127.0.0.1:4000")

      socketRef.current.connect()
      console.log(socketRef.current)

      socketRef.current.on('connect', function () {
        console.log("masuk")
      });
      socketRef.current.on("message", ({ name, message }) => {

        setChat([...chat, { name, message }])
      })
      return () => socketRef.current.disconnect()
    },
    [chat]
  )

  const onTextChange = (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  const onMessageSubmit = (e) => {
    const { name, message } = state
    console.log(name)
    console.log(message)
    socketRef.current.emit("message", { name, message })
    e.preventDefault()
    setState({ message: "", name })
  }

  const renderChat = () => {
    return chat.map(({ name, message }, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <h3>
          {name}: <span>{message}</span>
        </h3>
      </div>
    ))
  }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <form onSubmit={onMessageSubmit}>
        <h1>Messenger</h1>
        <div className="name-field">
          <TextField name="name" onChange={(e) => onTextChange(e)} value={state.name} label="Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            name="message"
            onChange={(e) => onTextChange(e)}
            value={state.message}
            id="outlined-multiline-static"
            variant="outlined"
            label="Message"
          />
        </div>
        <button>Send Message</button>
      </form>
      <div className="render-chat">
        <h1>Chat Log</h1>
        {renderChat()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it already, its because the version is not compatible between the server and the client